# Find the line number which contains the pattern using custom regex delimiter

Tags: text-processing, sed

As in [example](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/11/unix-sed-tutorial-append-insert-replace-and-count-file-lines/#count_lines) I'm trying to get line numbers which contains the pattern. My pattern contains slashes so I wanted to add custom delimiter.

This simple one works:

```
sed -n '/file/=' temp.txt
```

Using delimiter for string replace works too:

```
sed 's|file|gile|' temp.txt
```

but when I want to add delimiter to first example it doesn't:

```
sed -n '|file /etc|=' temp.txt
```

I know I can escape slashes but I would prefer to add custom delimiter. Any idea how to fix my command?

Comment: `sed -n '\|file /etc|='`

Comment: Thanks! What I found after your answer: 

\%regexp%
    (The % may be replaced by any other single character.)

    This also matches the regular expression regexp, but allows one to use a different delimiter than /. This is particularly useful if the regexp itself contains a lot of slashes, since it avoids the tedious escaping of every /. If regexp itself includes any delimiter characters, each must be escaped by a backslash (\).

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/77156/how-to-get-line-number-from-grep

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Stéphane [gave you](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182015/find-the-line-number-which-contains-the-pattern-with-custom-delimiter?noredirect=1#comment303012_182015) the `sed` solution:

```
sed -n  '\|file /etc|=' file
```

If you're open to using other tools, you can also do

```
grep -n 'file /etc' file
```

That will also print the line itself, to get the line number alone try:

```
grep -n 'file /etc' file | cut -d: -f 1
```

Or, you can use `perl`:

```
perl -lne 'm|file /etc| && print $.' file
```

Or `awk`:

```
awk '$0 ~ "file /etc" {print NR}'
```

Answer (score 4):

In all context addresses, you have to escape *the opening* delimiter, unless you're using the default `/`. Any following occurrences that are escaped are treated as the literal character, not as the ending delimiter.

- default delimiter:

  ```
  /start/,/end/{/pattern/d;}
  ```
- custom delimiter:

  ```
  \#start#,\#end#{\#pattern#d;}
  ```

See the [POSIX docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/sed.html):

> In a context address, the construction \cREc where c is any character
>   other than a backslash or newline character, is identical to /RE/ If
>   the character designated by c appears following a backslash, then it
>   is considered to be that literal character, which does not terminate
>   the RE. For example, in the context address \xabc\xdefx, the second x
>   stands for itself, so that the regular expression is abcxdef.

Similar description in GNU `sed man` page:

```
/regexp/
       Match lines matching the regular expression regexp.      
\cregexpc
       Match lines matching the regular expression regexp.  
       The c may be any character.
```

and FreeBSD `sed man` page:

```
In a context address, any character other than a backslash (``\'')
or newline character may be used to delimit the regular expression.
The opening delimiter   needs to be preceded by a backslash unless it
is a slash.  For example, the   context address \xabcx is equivalent
to /abc/.  Also, putting a backslash character before   the delimiting
character within the regular expression causes the character to be
treated literally.  For example, in the context address \xabc\xdefx,
the RE delimiter is an ``x'' and the second ``x'' stands for itself,
so that the regular expression is ``abcxdef''.
```