# Remove lines that contain file path using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a list of lines in a file that look like this:

```
6642a51e0ed5e6f89e5e4090b9aa0fb3  /home/device/eth0/uid
d66d1417251a9a151176c34acf046878  /home/device/eth0/uid64
db5c3c9d348ce26169c56901a7606961  /home/device/eth1/dhcp
226c1a53543bddcca5d136fdd5700f4c  /home/device/eth1/ipv4
13b376c06f904b607c2a23bd76115595  /home/device/eth1/netmask
```

I want to remove certain lines from this file without any blank lines.

I found `sed` to be the appropriate command, although I've tried a few ways and look at others work I still don't know how to do it.

This is what I have `sed -i "s|'/home/device/pn'|d" TestRun.chk`

But it doesnt work... I've read articles on how to break the slash and how to not use it. I just don't have a clue to that works for my situation.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Sample input:

```
6642a51e0ed5e6f89e5e4090b9aa0fb3  /home/device/eth0/uid
d66d1417251a9a151176c34acf046878  /home/device/eth0/uid64
db5c3c9d348ce26169c56901a7606961  /home/device/eth1/dhcp
226c1a53543bddcca5d136fdd5700f4c  /home/device/eth1/ipv4
13b376c06f904b607c2a23bd76115595  /home/device/eth1/netmask
```

After running the `sed` command to remove `/home/device/eth1/ipv4` the expected output:

```
6642a51e0ed5e6f89e5e4090b9aa0fb3  /home/device/eth0/uid
d66d1417251a9a151176c34acf046878  /home/device/eth0/uid64
db5c3c9d348ce26169c56901a7606961  /home/device/eth1/dhcp
13b376c06f904b607c2a23bd76115595  /home/device/eth1/netmask
```

Comment: I don't want to just remove visible characters in the line, I want to pull the line right out

Comment: `sed -e '/\/home\/device\/eth1\/ipv4/d' <file`

Comment: Why are you using `-e`?

Comment: Well, get rid of those double quotes and use single quotes instead, remove the `s` (you're not substituting anything) and [escape the opening delimiter](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/182015): `sed '\|/home/device/eth1/ipv4|d'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sed`, you can do:

```
$ sed -i '\| pattern to match |d' File
```

This will remove lines containing `pattern to match` in File.

Using grep, you can do:

```
$ echo "$(grep -v "pattern to match" File)" > File
```

The `-v` option allows grepping of lines not containing `pattern to match`, which is then redirected back to File.

Answer (score -1):

As I see your file contains special character / you can this command to remove any line you should specify string characteristic of each line for example the 2nd line is "uid64":

```
sed -i '\|uid64|d' testRun.chk
In my pc it's print this without blank line :
6642a51e0ed5e6f89e5e4090b9aa0fb3  /home/device/eth0/uid
db5c3c9d348ce26169c56901a7606961  /home/device/eth1/dhcp
226c1a53543bddcca5d136fdd5700f4c  /home/device/eth1/ipv4
13b376c06f904b607c2a23bd76115595  /home/device/eth1/netmask
```

As you can see there is no the 2nd line you can do this for the following line "`sed -i '\|ipv4|d' testRun.chk`" and so one.

Good luck!

Comment: This answer just looks like a duplicate of the first answer